# Power pivot DAX - reference current row in measure calculation

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a fact table in power pivot that i would like to sum up the stock transfer-in by branch and itemno. To better illustrate my problem, please refer to the mock up example below.

**mockup example**

[image]

In the above example, i can use a sumifs function in the outcome table to evaluate [To party] and [itemno]. However I could not get this work in power pivot DAX.

Below is the real business case illustration.

**real business case**

[image]

I manage to hardcode the [branch] code in the formula but this only works for a particular branch. My DAX formula is as below:

```
=CALCULATE(SUMx(ALL(f_transaction_detail[branch]),[Sum of totalbaseqty]),f_transaction_detail[doctype]="Transfer Note",f_transaction_detail[accountcode]="003")
```

Can anyone show me some guidance of how to crack this DAX formula?

Comment: If you need to calculate the Quantity per branch, you can add `[Branch]` field to `Columns` pane in the Pivot table fields menu. You will get the Quantity per `[To Party]` and `[ItemNo]` for each `[Branch]`.

Comment: yes, I know I can do that to achieve that. In fact, I was using this method to validate my DAX expression most of the time. But I want to make it an explicit measure as I will need it in further calculation.

Comment: So you want a measure per branch? If so you need to create each by explicitely filter each branch as you are doing in the DAX expression in the OP.